# Ruby Whois Queries Timeout

Tags: ruby, whois, whois-ruby

I am using the Ruby Whois gem at http://ruby-whois.org to automate retrieval of Whois records for various websites.

At the moment, I am performing a few thousand queries per day. I am noticing that *many* of the queries I make result in Timeout errors or throttling errors, usually involving Verisign.

Is there any way I can get around these limitations? Are there commonly used APIs that may be useful?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of whois interfaces have request limits to prevent possible abuses. That's the reason of the errors you are getting.

There is no easy way to get around this limit. The most common is a large set of IPs to send the requests from.